# Grouping dates on month SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(
     cid int,
     open_date datetime
);  

INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01'), (1, '2020-01-30'),
       (1, '2020-02-01'), (1, '2020-02-27'),
       (1, '2021-01-12'), (1, '2021-01-30'),
       (2, '2020-01-01'), (2, '2020-01-30'),
       (2, '2020-02-01'), (2, '2020-02-27'),
       (2, '2021-01-12'), (2, '2021-01-30');
```

Expected output:

[image]

I need each cust id's min and max date of each month. I'm expecting use of window function to group and based on result of window function again group the date based on grp number

Comment: What is the difference in logic between row 1, 2  and 3.. for row 2 I see they are in different year.. for row 1 and 3 even if they are in same month but different year..they are being grouped separately

Comment: yes exactly ... row 1 and 3  are in different year ..so different row

Comment: Then shouldn't 01.02.2020 and 27.02.2021 be grouped differently as they are in different year ?

Comment: sory ..i have updated expected result..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a window function.  It think you do it with a `group by` like this:

```
CREATE   TABLE #tbl
  (cid int,open_date datetime);  

INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES (1, '2020-01-01'), (1, '2020-01-30'),
       (1, '2020-02-01'), (1, '2020-02-27'),
       (1, '2021-01-12'), (1, '2021-01-30'),
       (2, '2020-01-01'), (2, '2020-01-30'),
       (2, '2020-02-01'), (2, '2020-02-27'),
       (2, '2021-01-12'), (2, '2021-01-30');

select cid, min(open_date) min, max(open_date) max
  from #tbl
 group by cid
     , datepart(year, open_date)
     , datepart(month, open_date)
```

Here is the output of query (using the data provided in the question):

```
cid min                     max
1   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-30 00:00:00.000
1   2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 2020-02-27 00:00:00.000
1   2021-01-12 00:00:00.000 2021-01-30 00:00:00.000
2   2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-30 00:00:00.000
2   2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 2020-02-27 00:00:00.000
2   2021-01-12 00:00:00.000 2021-01-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I know how to do in group by ..but i  want to window function to to group the data and based on grp value again group   ..

Comment: Is there a particular window function that you'd like to use?  Or, do you mean you'd like to use a Common Table Expression?

Comment: am expecting use any ranking function function to group the data

Comment: There isn't a place in the desired output where you have any sort of rank.  Why would you use a ranking function to group the data in this case?

Comment: i have corrected the output..  u can use cte but i need to grp based on month..

Answer (score 1):

I think @user212514 solution is valid but if you want to use window function you can make sure of first_value to get your desired result. It is the same as provided result by user.

```
select distinct  min(cid) over (partition by  cid , Year(open_date), Month(open_date) order by open_date) CID, 
first_value (open_date) over (partition by  cid,   Year(open_date), Month(open_date) order by open_date) Min_date, 
first_value(open_date) over (partition by    cid, Year(open_date),Month(open_date) order by open_date desc) Max_date   from #tbl
order by cid  ,Min_date
```

Comment: Ur answer is perfect but i need some thing Grp  based on Grp i need to group